# If $H$ is a special subgroup of $G$, then is $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

A teacher shared with me his textbook (writing in progress) about group theory and this exercise is at the end of the first chapter.

The whole problem:
A subgroup $H$ of $G$ is special if for all $x \in G\backslash H$ and $y \in G$ exists only one $a \in H$ such that $y^{-1}xy=a^{-1}xa$. Prove that if $H$ is a special subgroup of $G$, then $H \unlhd G$.

I tried by contradiction, suppose $ H $ is not a normal subgroup of $G$. Then, there is $g \in G$ and $h \in H$ such that $gHg^{-1}\neq H $. Equivalently, there is $g \in G$ and $h \in H$ such that $ghg^{-1} \in G \backslash H $. Since $H$ is a special group, there is only one $a \in H$ such that $y^{-1}(ghg^{-1})y = a^{-1}(ghg^{-1})a$.
What i'm trying to do is to show that there is more than one $a \in H$ that satisfies this property.

Comment: Thank you for including context. Where did you encounter this exercise?

Comment: A teacher shared with me his textbook (writing in progress) about group theory and this exercise is at the end of the first chapter.

Comment: I edited in your comment about where you got the question from, as comments are temporary (they can be deleted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to pick $y$ carefully.

Say $h\in H$, $g\in G$, and $x=ghg^{-1}\notin H$.

Then letting $y=g^{-1}$, there exists a unique $a\in H$ such that $yxy^{-1}=axa^{-1}$. Writing this out, that means that
$$\begin{align*}
h &= (g^{-1}g)h(g^{-1}g)^{-1}\\
   &= g^{-1}(ghg^{-1}) (g^{-1})^{-1}\\
&= yxy^{-1}\\
&= axa^{-1}.
\end{align*}$$

But then we also have that
$$(ha)x(ha)^{-1} = h(axa^{-1})h^{-1} = hhh^{-1}=h=yxy^{-1}.$$
Now bring it home.

---

The result holds without uniqueness of $a$, though; it is enough that such an $a$ exist. From $h=axa^{-1}$ with $h,a\in H$ we immediately conclude that $x\in H$.